# How to access dictionary passed as generic or even dynamic type

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, dictionary

Let's have function `Process<T>(T data)`. The `T` might be "any" (means supported) type, eg. `int` also as `Dictionary<U,V>`, where U, V are "any" types, etc. We can detect the `T` is dictionary using code:

```
var type = typeof(T); // or data.GetType();

if (   (type.IsGenericType)
    && (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>)))
{
    var dict = data as Dictionary<,>; // FIXME: Make dictionary from data

    foreach (kv in dict)
    {
        ProcessKey(kv.Key  );
        ProcessVal(kv.Value);
    }
}
```

Is there any way how to interpret data as dictionary or we just need separate `ProcessInt()`, `ProcessDict<T>() where T: Dictionary<U, V>`, etc?

Second level of confusion: When the function would have the form `Process(dynamic data)`, is there any way how to access the data for the case its type is `Dictionary<U, V>` (please note the U, V are again "any" supported types)?

Comment: Cant you detect what kind of types are the key=>value pairs in order to cast to the right dictionary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamics:

```
  if ((type.IsGenericType) && (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>)))
            {
                var dict = data as IDictionary;
                foreach (dynamic entity in dict)
                {
                    object key = entity.Key;
                    object value = entity.Value;


                    ProcessKey(key);
                    ProcessVal(value);
                }
            }
```

This way you can have `ProcessKey` and `ProcessVal` expecting object.

Comment: Of course! Thanks. Totally forget the IDictionary ;)